# Ansible YAML syntax error on inline array containing dictionary

Tags: yaml, ansible

I have an Ansible playbook which includes another playbook and then attempts to pass a variable to that playbook. It works fine, but I get a YAML syntax error whenever the variable I construct contains a dictionary:

```
- hosts: all
- include: other_playbook.yml var1=[ {key: value} ]
```

What syntax can I use to pass dictionary variables to another playbook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also pass variables with this syntax:

```
- include: other_playbook.yml
  vars:
    var1:
      - key: value
```

From the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#task-include-files-and-encouraging-reuse):

> Starting in 1.0, variables can also be passed to include files using an alternative syntax, **which also supports structured variables**